# Calculate internal response time of a java based server

Tags: java, testing, logging, web, log4j

I need to calculate the internal response time in context of a stress test.
I can do a load test with pylot running from a different server. How can i calculate the internal response time which doesn't include network latency. I can run pylot from the same machine but it doesn't seem a good idea.
I can think of using logging facilities like log4j and log times of receiving and sending of requests and responses respectively.

Are there other good ways of doing this... Or how do people do this at present ?

Answer (score 1):

I would normally create a servlet filter or similar that captures the request/response in the server prior to dispatch to the servlet, and record the amount of time taken by the servlet there.

Where I've done this before, I've recorded the stats in the servlet filter and calculated min/max/average and presented this info in another servlet or via JMX - it makes production issue diagnosis very easy. I also use the filter to log the request and response, so the log files record each access.

Another (cruder?) approach would be to record an average network latency via ping or similar and subtract that from the recorded client time. Don't forget to subtract for the request *and* the response. This is very crude, however, and doesn't take into account (say) stream decompression/marshalling etc. at the server end.